# Move Lumen Application from Localhost to DigitalOcean

Tags: php, mysql, digital-ocean, lumen-5.2

I am trying to move my Lumen application from my localhost to DigitalOcean. The localhost application works fine. I have uploaded my files through FileZilla and also pointed my document root to

```
var/www/html/resources/views/index.php
```

When I enter the domain name, it opens correctly. However, when I click on the login on this page, 2 things happen.

1. PDOException in Connector.php line 55:
   SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2. my domain name reverts back to the original localhost IP address and corresponding suffixes. For example: Instead of

   http://domain.com/login
   I get http://999.222.111.9/login

My .env is as follows

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=appkey

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=***************

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.fatcow.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=**********
MAIL_PASSWORD=**********

CACHE_DRIVER=memcached
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

and my database.php is:

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port'      => env('DB_PORT', 3306),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'database'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', '**************'),
        'charset'   => env('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8'),
        'collation' => env('DB_COLLATION', 'utf8_unicode_ci'),
        'prefix'    => env('DB_PREFIX', ''),
        'timezone'  => env('DB_TIMEZONE', '+00:00'),
        'strict'    => env('DB_STRICT_MODE', false),
    ],
```

Other details: I don't have phpmyadmin installed in my droplet because my database size is too big to upload to phpmyadmin.

I have not imported my database to mysql because the last time I tried, it did not import all the tables.

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: For the first error are you sure you have a database named *database* and the user *root* has access to it with the provided password? For the second error add in **.env** this `APP_URL=http://domain.com`, which is your domain and try again.

Comment: For the first, I just used database as a placeholder, but my actual database is correct. also, well, root@localhost does, but since it's on cloud hosting and I don't change any data, is localhost the host on the server? or still my local machine?

Comment: Also, I added that bit of info to the .env but I'm still getting the same error. And if I check the site on local, I get the same error also. :(

Comment: I'm not sure if *root@localhost* would be correct. You should try with your server IP or check on which port the MySQL is running.

Comment: okay the database connection works now, but my 2nd problem still happens. how do I change the redirection? :) @TheFallen

Comment: If adding `APP_URL` doesn't work try adding a sever alias in the virtual host.

Comment: it still didn't work. I think it's a configuration issue somewhere but I can't figure it out.